# JComponent with no LayoutManager in JScrollPane

Tags: jscrollpane, jcomponent

I want to show a JComponent with no LayoutManager in a JScrollPane. That means the LayoutManager of the JComponent is set to null. The problem is that the JScrollPane does not show an element with no LayoutManager. I would like to know what a JScrollPane changes on its element and what not. Can anyone help me?

I know that using a LayoutManager is recommended, but in this case I want to position all elements individually and I don't want that anything else changes their size or location in their containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using null LayoutManager, you have to specify your bounds:

`setBounds()` method coveres the task of `setLocation()` method.

for example, `setBounds(x,y,w,h)`;

first 2 will set the x/y location of that component with respect to its container. second 2(w/h) will set the size of that component.

in other words:-

`setBounds(int x, int y, int witdh, int height)` – Sets the component’s size and location
`setLocation(int x, int y)` – Sets the component’s location